# Where are session variables stored in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-variables

hard disk, main memory or somewhere else. I am not asking for the case where these are stored in database.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look into [sessions chapter of rails security guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions) - it answers your question in detail and will help you to understand how it works.

Comment: thanks for the link, it helped me to understand about sessions and how wrong my concept was. I should really read this guide fully. So, if the browser cookies are reset, the data in `session` variable will be lost, if we are using `cookiestore`, right?

Comment: Yes, but they will be lost even if you're using database to store session - the session id will be lost in this case - so basically the result will be the same.

Answer (score 22):

By default rails uses cookies to store the session data. All data is stored in the client, not on the server.

Comment: isnt cookies stored in client side and session in server side? I am asking about session variables and not about a request session.

Comment: Cookies are sent between client and server with each request/response.  Just read about CookieStore in the rails guide linked in the other answer.

Comment: oh..I feel like I have a lot to study..I had a wrong concept that `session` variables are stored in server side and `cookie` variables are stored in the client side. So, `session` variables will also be lost if the browser cookies are reset, if we are using `cookiestore`, right?

Comment: what about when you are accessing session in rails with a mobile app using backbone? would the same logic apply? how would it set the cookie if the authentication was requested by json? would it make a difference?

Comment: @rubyprince you're not far off. Session variables can be stored on the server side(in the database) however the default is in cookies. Resetting cookie will reset both types of session stores. This guide was the most helpful for me: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

Comment: ok i agree with the fact that session key gets stored in browser as cookie, but when browser sends a request to server it matches the session key, for that server has to keep it somewhere to match with it, correct me if I am wrong? If not then where it is stored on server?

Comment: @kamal Not the session key is stored in a cookie, the whole session data is stored in a cookie (still talking about Rails's default). So there is nothing stored or matched on the server. Rails 4 uses EncryptedCookieStore, so the only thing that's happening on server-side, is encrypting/decrypting the session data.

Comment: @wanderfalke But how server is identifying that this session key is valid and attached to which user, as you said `So there is nothing stored or matched on the server` when server has no trace of this session data?

Comment: @kamal The session is not attached to a user, but to a request. And it is sent on each request to a server and sent back with the response as a cookie (the whole session data, not just session id). If you use EncryptedCookieStore, then it is ensured, that no one has tampered with the session data.

Answer (score 14):

#### In Rails, session object is sent back and forth inside cookies.

---

When you set `session[:user_id] = 3` inside of your controller action, the response sent from that action will have a header `Set-Cookie: my-session-cookie`.
From now on browser will automatically send a header `Cookie: my-session-cookie` back to server on every request.

This is how my-session-cookie usually looks:

```
_Hello_session=BAh7B0kiD3%3D%3D--dc40a55cd52fe32bb3b84ae0608956dfb5824689
```

which translates into:

```
_Hello_session=<encrypted user_id=3>--<digital signature>
```

- `Hello` is the name of your Rails app.
- To prevent evil people from
  understanding `a=b` string, it's **encrypted**.
- To prevent evil
  people from tampering cookies, **digital signature** is used.

---

Both encryption (and decryption), and signing (and verifying) are done using a server-side secret key `secrets.secret_key_base` stored in `/config/secrets.yml`.

Comment: (Rails does offer other options for session storage, including `sessionId+database` and `nonencrypted cookie-based sessions`, but this one is default)

Comment: Thank you. I understood this after asking this question in 2011. I didnt have a solid understanding of how and what cookies are back then. But I learned it afterwards, this question being the trigger point. 

Thank you for the answer as it will help other people who are in similar condition as I was years ago. +1 for the well thought out, to the point answer.